# Storing cookies from WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

I'm doing a project where I have to **scrape** the HTML since the website does not provide an API. Currently, I am logging the user by injecting javascript on to the website. The user input there user and password in a text field and when they hit log in it calls a function that will run this code.

```
static let loginView = WKWebView()

@objc func handleLogin() {
    guard let user = username.text, !user.isEmpty else { return }
    guard let pass = password.text, !pass.isEmpty else { return }
        
    view.endEditing(true)
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    loginButton.isEnabled = false

    LoginController.loginView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('username').value='\(user)'", completionHandler: nil)
    LoginController.loginView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('password').value='\(pass)'", completionHandler: nil)
    LoginController.loginView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('btn-login')[0].click()", completionHandler: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.me.ie") else { return }    
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    LoginController.loginView.load(request)
    LoginController.loginView.navigationDelegate = self
}
```

For some reason when the user close the app. they have to login back in but when I am doing it through the website it saves the cookie and the user does not have to log back in. Is there a way where I can save the cookie so the user won't have to go through this process.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @MohsinKhubaibAhmed No, I'm trying to see if anyone can do this but it seems there isn't an answer to this problem!